# Evaluate the triple integral where D is the region inside the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ which is bounded...?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the triple integral where D is the region inside the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ which is bounded  below by the plane z=0 and bounded above by the plane 2x+4y+z=11.

I started this problem by changing into cylindrical coordinates and got this triple integral and was wondering if you can give me an okay before I start solving it. Thank you!

$$
\int_{-1}^1 \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{11-2rcos\theta -4rsin\theta} r(rcos\theta)^2 dzd\theta dr
$$

Comment: $r$ should run from $0$ to $1$. Use 2-dimensional polar-coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

The Jacobian of the cylindrical coordinates should be $r$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{gathered}
  \int_{ - 1}^1 {\int_{ - \sqrt {1 - {x^2}} }^{\sqrt {1 - {x^2}} } {\int_0^{11 - 2x - 4y} {dzdydx = } } } \int_{ - 1}^1 {\int_{ - \sqrt {1 - {x^2}} }^{\sqrt {1 - {x^2}} } {(11 - 2x - 4y} )dydx}  \hfill \\
   = \int_0^1 {\int_0^{2\pi } {11 - 2\cos (\phi ) - 4sin(\phi )} rd\varphi dr}  = 11\pi  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$

Comment: I don't understand how you went from a triple integral to a double integral? The answer is incorrect

Comment: @Ayoshna: The function in triple integral is the constant function $1$, so $$\int\limits_o^{11 - 2x - 4y} {dz}  = 11 - 2x - 4y$$